# jquery solution for clicking a link and changing the background image while also displaying another set of images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting a set of images to display when I click on a link. Basically I want to change the background image to a seperate image for each link while also displaying a div full of images that are different for each link as well. What I've come up with so far changes the background image, but the secondary div images display though only when clicked in order (first, second, third, fourth) and can't be selected randomly. Also when going through the links and starting back at the first I have to click twice because the first click hides the div of images and basically the second click starts the process over again.

Here is the code I've come up with so far:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#picture-div").hide();
    //alert('jq is working');
    $(".this-class").click(function(){
        ShowPic(this)
    });

    function ShowPic (pic)
    {
        var imgs = ["../images/numbers-01.jpg", "../images/numbers-02.jpg",
                  "../images/numbers-06.jpg", "../images/numbers-09.jpg"];

        var th = $(pic);
        var picLink = th.attr("data-img-src");
        //alert(picLink);

        for (var x=0; x<imgs.length; x++)
        {
          var imgList = imgs[x];
          //alert(imgs[x]);
          if (imgList == picLink)
          {
              $("body").css("background-image", 'url(' + imgList + ')');
          }
        }
    }

  });
</script>

<script>
  $(function(){
    var count = 1;
    $(".previewBox").hide();
    $(".this-class").click(function(){
      SmallDiv(this)
    });

    function SmallDiv (obj)
    {
      var th = $(obj);
      var rel = th.attr("rel");

      if (rel == 1 && count == 1)
      {
          //alert(rel);
          $("#img-1").show();
          $("#img-2").add("#img-3").add("#img-4").hide();
          count++;
      }
      else if (rel == 2 && count == 2)
      {
          $("#img-2").show();
          $("#img-1").add("#img-3").add("#img-4").hide();
          count++;
      }
        else if (rel == 3 && count == 3)
      {
          $("#img-3").show();
          $("#img-1").add("#img-2").add("#img-4").hide();
          count++;
      }
        else if (rel == 4 && count == 4)
      {
          $("#img-4").show();
          $("#img-1").add("#img-2").add("#img-3").hide();
          count++;
      }
          else
        {
            $(".previewBox").hide();
            count = 1;
        }
    }

  });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li><a rel="1" class="this-class" data-img-src="../images/numbers-01.jpg">First       Link</a></li>
  <br><br>
  <li><a rel="2" class="this-class" data-img-src="../images/numbers-02.jpg">Second Link</a></li>
  <br><br>
  <li><a rel="3" class="this-class" data-img-src="../images/numbers-06.jpg">Third Link</a></li>
  <br><br>
  <li><a rel="4" class="this-class" data-img-src="../images/numbers-09.jpg">Fourth Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="img-1" class="previewBox">
  <ul>
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/0.jpg">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/1.jpg">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/2.jpg">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/5.jpg">
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="img-2" class="previewBox">
  <ul>
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/0.jpg">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/1.jpg">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/6.jpg">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/7.jpg">
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="img-3" class="previewBox">
  <ul>
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/1.jpg">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/2.jpg">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/6.jpg">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/7.jpg">
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="img-4" class="previewBox">
  <ul>
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/6.jpg">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/1.jpg">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/0.jpg">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="images/5.jpg">
  </ul>
</div>
```